# Pushing new function into an array - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, function

I cannot get this to work:

```
var global_variables = {
    players: []
}; 

var player = function(properties){
    this.width = properties.width;                            
    this.height = properties.height;
    this.position = properties.position;
    this.position.x = properties.position.x;
    this.position.y = properties.position.y;
}

function load_players(){
    global_variables.players.push(
        [
            new player(
                {
                    width: 10,
                    height: 10,
                    position: {
                        x: 50,
                        y: 50
                    },
                    colour: '#ff0000'
                }
            )
        ]
    );
}


 function init(){ 
    var ctx = load_canvas();
    load_players();

    for(a in global_variables.players){
        var _this = global_variables.players[a];
        alert(_this.colour);
    }
}
```

alert(_this.colour) just alerts undefined. Any ideas?

Comment: `load_players` was not called?

Comment: I updated the code to represent where i would call it... And again. hehe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You were trying to loop before calling `init`
2. You were pushing your player instance wrapped in an array. You just wanted to push the player.
3. Don't use `for ... in ...` on an array. Use a regular loop or use `forEach` like I did.
4. You were never actually setting the `colour` property to your instance.

http://jsfiddle.net/GLsR2/

Here's the code from the fiddle:

```
var global_variables = {
    players: []
}; 

var player = function(properties){
    this.width = properties.width;                            
    this.height = properties.height;
    this.position = properties.position;
    this.position.x = properties.position.x;
    this.position.y = properties.position.y;
    this.colour = properties.colour;
}

function load_players(){
    global_variables.players.push(
        new player(
                {
                    width: 10,
                    height: 10,
                    position: {
                        x: 50,
                        y: 50
                    },
                    colour: '#ff0000'
                }
            )
      );
}


init();

global_variables.players.forEach(function(player) {
   alert(player.colour); 
});

function init(){ 
    load_players();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You get `undefined` from `_this.colour` for two reasons:

1. You don't set a `colour` property in your constructor
2. Rather than pushing each new player into the array you are pushing a one-element array containing the new player. That is, you're creating an array of arrays.

Add this to the constructor:

```
    this.colour = properties.colour;
```

And then remove the square brackets from in the `load_players()` function:

```
function load_players(){
    global_variables.players.push(        
            new player({
                    width: 10,
                    height: 10,
                    position: {
                        x: 50,
                        y: 50
                    },
                    colour: '#ff0000'
            })
    );
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ZACnC/

Comment: Oh god.. the colour not being set.. how embarrassing.. thank you so much for taking the time to out my noobish school boy error of being a noob.

toolateforcode.com

Comment: I changed it to: global_variables.players = [
            new player(... 

Thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

When you are pushing on to `global_variables.players`, you are pushing an array containing the `new Player` object, not the object itself.

You don't need the `[]` when using `.push`.

```
function load_players(){
    global_variables.players.push(
        new player({
            width: 10,
            height: 10,
            position: {
                x: 50,
                y: 50
            },
            colour: '#ff0000'
        })
    );
}
```

P.S. Don't use `for...in` for arrays.  Just use a normal `for`.

```
for(var a = 0, len = global_variables.players.length; a < len; a++){
    var _this = global_variables.players[a];
    alert(_this.colour);
}
```

P.P.S. You need to add `this.colour = properties.colour;` to your `player` constructor.